# Why is the word order in "To what tense I can refer this sentence?" wrong?

Tags: word-order, questions

Why are the word orders of the questions wrong and in what way I can ask the same question (rephrase)?

1. **To what** tense I can refer this sentence?
2. **To whom** I can give an apple?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In interrogative questions, an auxiliary verb precedes the subject. It's called *subject-auxiliary inversion*(or *subject-operator inversion* if you follow LGSWE).

So it should be

> To what tense **can I** refer this sentence?
>
> To whom **can I** give an apple?

Those contructions are rather formal, the casual way to rephrase it is

> What tense can I refer this sentence to?
>
> Who can I give an apple to?